# hql Hibernate insert query returning unexpected token: INSERT

Tags: hibernate

I am new to Hibernate i am trying to insert data into a table using hql. below is the code. when in run the code i am getting the below exception. i tried googling everyone wrote the code in the same way. i guess something is missing in my code

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        SessionFactory factory = conf.buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
        Query qry = session.createQuery("INSERT INTO Item (userName, age, id)"+" SELECT e.userName, e.age, e.id from Employee e ");

        //qry.setParameter(0, 1);
        int res = qry.executeUpdate();
        txn.commit();
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxError: unexpected token: INSERT near line 1, column 1 [INSERT INTO Item (userName, age, id)

Caused by: line 1:1: unexpected token: INSERT
```

Comment: Does your code work with a SELECT query?

Comment: Yes. it is working for select, update, delete

Comment: Could you update your post with the DDL script of Employee and Item Table?